# Pandas unique count of number of records in a column where mutliple values are present in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to count the unique number of ***Customer_Key*** where the column ***Broad_Category*** has both the values **A** and **B** grouped by values in column ***Month***. The sample dataframe is as follows

| Customer_Key | Category | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ck123 | A | 2 |
| ck234 | A | 2 |
| ck234 | B | 2 |
| ck680 | A | 3 |
| ck123 | B | 3 |
| ck123 | A | 3 |
| ck356 | B | 3 |
| ck345 | A | 4 |

The expected outcome is

| Month | Unique Customers |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 |

I'm not able to think of something here. Any lead/help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.*emphasized text*

Comment: Customer key 'ck_234' is the only customer in Month 2 who has both A and B values in Category column. Similarly, for month 3, it's 'ck_123' whereas, for month 4, there's no such customer

Comment: Thanks @BigBen for pointing it out. Apologies for the confusion, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
df.groupby(['Customer_Key', 'Month']) \
  .sum() \
  .query("Category in ('AB','BA')") \
  .groupby('Month') \
  .count() \
  .rename(columns={'Category': 'Unique Customers'})
```

Edit...

The issue with this solution is that it does not count months with 0. I have prepared a fix:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""ck123    A   2
ck234   A   2
ck234   B   2
ck680   A   3
ck123   B   3
ck123   A   3
ck356   B   3
ck345   A   4""")

df1 = df.groupby(['Customer_Key', 'Month']) \
        .sum() \
        .reset_index()

def map_categories(row):
    if row['Category'] in ('AB', 'BA'):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df1['Unique Customers'] = df1.apply(lambda row: map_categories(row), axis=1)

df1 = df1.groupby('Month')['Unique Customers'].sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to accomplish it

first its grouping by Month and Customer that get us the customer within a month with the count of the categories. The result is further grouped by Month and we choose the max count.

Decrementing the count give us the required count of unique customer belonging to both categories

hope it helps

```
df2=df.groupby(['Month','Customer_Key']).count().reset_index().groupby(['Month'])['Category'].max().reset_index() 
df2['Category'] = df2['Category'] -1
df2.rename(columns={'Category': 'Unique Cusomter'}, inplace=True)
df2
```

```
    Month   Unique Cusomter
0   2   1
1   3   1
2   4   0
```